# POSIX regular expression to extract a substring

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to extract the substring in place of `md5_object_id` from the following string:

```
{
      "associatedEntity": "60056",
      "associatedObject": "md5_object_id",
      "associatedAttr": "END22206",
      "associatedAttr": ""
}
```

The md5_object_id is dynamic and it can take any valid md5 string.
I tried some regex, but I need the most efficient one, since I am using the extracted substring in an SQL Join query. I am using PostgreSQL 9.2, so json functions are not available.

Comment: Is that a *JSON* object or something (please provide appropriate tags)? What exactly do you mean by *"extract the substring in place of `md5_object_id`"*? Provide some example input data and expected output. Also it's important you post what you tried (*"I tried some regex"* is not enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you would use regex to extract it:

`(?<=associatedObject": )"([^"]*)"`

[Regex101 Example](http://regex101.com/r/lD4pI5)

Comment: thanks but, it is not working for postgresql. getting exception:
ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
SQL state: 2201B

Comment: A slight modification did the job:(?:associatedObjectID": )"([^"]*)"

Comment: Nice. That way is actually better, because you can use repetition quantifiers inside the non-capture group.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL 9.3 and above, use the `json` type and the `->>` operator:

```
regress=> SELECT json('{
      "associatedEntity": "60056",
      "associatedObject": "md5_object_id",
      "associatedAttr": "END22206",
      "associatedAttr": ""
}')->> 'associatedObject';
   ?column?    
---------------
 md5_object_id
(1 row)
```

Since you didn't specify your version, I'm going to happily assume you're on the current release, so you can use this.

---

Using a regular expression for this job is a *terrible* idea; like parsing HTML with regular expressions, it's using the wrong tool for the job. So instead, use a procedural language with a json library:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_get_key(object json, keyname text) returns text as $$
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
return decode_json($_[0])->{$_[1]};
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;

postgres=# SELECT json_get_key( json('{"a":1, "b":"c"}') , 'b');
json_get_key 
--------------
 c
(1 row)
```

or:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_get_key_py(object json, keyname text) returns text AS $$
import json
return json.loads(object)[keyname]
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

postgres=# SELECT json_get_key_py( json('{"a":1, "b":"c"}') , 'b');
 json_get_key_py 
-----------------
 c
(1 row)
```

---

Can't use procedural languages either? Your best bet is probably to fetch this to the client and decode it there.

If you can restrict your json to a simplified form that doesn't use unicode escapes, doesn't allow escaped quotes, doesn't allow nested objects as values, etc, it may be possible to use a regex in Pg, but it's still a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry, It is PostgreSQL 9.2, so json operators are not available

Comment: @user1982817 .... and that's why you include the versions of the software you're using in questions.

Comment: @user1982817 Added a "plan B" approach.

Comment: I will use the regex or the function to extract the value directly inside the "ON" condition of an inner join. In this case, as you said the regex is terrible, but for the time being I will stick with the regex given by Vasili Syrakis. Later I will use plan B approach with my seniors approval.